# Common Lisp Timer

Tags: timer, common-lisp

I would like to start a timer in my common lisp application that after a certain amount of time it will call a certain method.  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

Would something as simple as [SLEEP](http://l1sp.org/cl/sleep) work?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.cliki.net/TIMER implements relative time based scheduling, which i THINK is what you mean

Comment: Just a note that this points to Xach's link as in jkndrkn's answer.

Comment: @FrankShearar And for whatever reason, this answer (which was posted two minutes *earlier*) has one fewer votes.  Maybe people appreciate the formatting and attribution in the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/)-dependent, but you might want to try out Zach Beane's [TIMER](http://www.xach.com/lisp/timer/doc.html).

Answer (score 4):

### With SBCL: `make-timer` and `schedule-timer`

SBCL has built-in functions for this.

> SBCL supports a system-wide event scheduler implemented on top of setitimer that also works with threads but does not require a separate scheduler thread.

This examples executes a function after 2 seconds:

```
(schedule-timer (make-timer (lambda ()
                              (write-line "Hello, world")
                              (force-output)))
                2)
```

Among other methods we have `unschedule-timer` and `list-all-timers`.

Xach Bean's timer dates from 2003. It is possible these SBCL methods are more recent.

#### With Clerk, "a cron-like scheduler with a sane DSL"

With the [Clerk](https://github.com/tsikov/clerk) library, we can run regular jobs:

```
(job "Say 'Hi' all the time" every 5.seconds (print "Hi"))
```

This will run every 5 seconds. Without "every" it would be a one-time job:

```
(job "Extraordinary event" in 5.days (send-mail "Don't forget X"))
```

where we can use any word instead of "in".

#### See also

I also encountered but didn't try https://github.com/Shinmera/simple-tasks

Answer (score 1):

You could use CL's SLEEP, unless you need more precise timing (since SLEEP is permitted to use approximate timing.)

In LispWorks, if more precise timing is needed, one could use [LispWorks' timer scheduling interface](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw71/LW/html/lw-148.htm#988872).

Note that, same as Zach Beane's TIMER, this is not implementation-agnostic.