# Abort function after X seconds - lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I've been searching a way to stop a function after X seconds on lisp and I haven't found anything and have no ideia how to do it.

It's for finding heuristic weights on a function for a tetris game and if the weights are bad the program will run for more than 30 seconds and I don't want that. Any ideias, please?

Comment: There are answers to this, but they won't be portable;  the Common Lisp standard doesn't include multiprocessing/threading/etc., concepts.  You tagged the question with [tag:clisp];  are you using the CLISP implementation?  Or some other implementation?  That said, [bordeaux-threads](https://common-lisp.net/project/bordeaux-threads/) provides a compatibility layer over some implementation threading APIs.  Once you have some multi-threading working, you may find the answers to [Common Lisp Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986822/1281433) useful.

Comment: While those links are useful, I *really* like [Vatine's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003871/1281433).

Comment: If my guess is correct, the context of this question is an artificial intelligence (AI) project where there is a tournament to positively add to the grade of the best projects.  A timeout is provided for the function called during each match (find best move(s), solution(s), etc.) that, when elapsed, will disqualify the project for that match.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible way is to pass down an "expiry timer" and check if the current time is later than the expiry time in every iteration and, if it has expired, return the best solution so far. The standard function `get-universal-time` may be useful, but gives you a minimal granularity of seconds. A rough skeleton below. If you use recursive functions, simply pass the expiry timer down with whatever else you pass down and use that as your first recursion termination criterion.

```
(defun do-tetris-stuff (tetris-weights expiry-time)
  (let ((best-solution nil))
    (loop while (and (<= expiry-time (get-universal-time))
                     (not (good-enough-p best-solution)))
          do (let ((next-solution ...))
               (when (better-than-p next-solution best-solution)
                 (setf best-solution next-solution))))
    best-solution))
```

Comment: I really like this answer.  It shows that this can be done without any multithreading, timers, etc., so long as there's some way to periodically check the time.  +1 (and more if I could).

Comment: Rather than specifying an expiry-time, which makes the caller responsible, you could also do `(defun do-stuff (weights &optional (timeout 30) &aux (expiry-time (+ (get-universal-time) timeout))) ...)` which lets the caller specify a timeout in seconds, and computes the expiry time as that number of seconds plus the current universal time.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor There are some problems, but this is portable and frequently you have something like "search depth" limiting the traversal of the solution space anyway. You're out of luck (or in system-dependent code) if you need a finer granularity than "one second" though.

Comment: I would think that by using [`get-internal-real-time`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_in.htm) one could have a time granularity much more fine than that of `get-universal-time`.

Comment: @Renzo But you would still need to figure out at what pace the internal time ticks in your implementation. Not exactly a hard problem, I admit.

Comment: @Vatine, that's not a problem, you already have [`internal-time-units-per-second`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_intern.htm).

Answer (score 9):

Common Lisp has a library for that: [Trivial Timeout](http://quickdocs.org/trivial-timeout/).

The API is simple: [Trivial Timeout API](http://quickdocs.org/trivial-timeout/api).